# How to edit the existing contacts programmatically in iPhone

Tags: iphone, contacts

I want to edit the contact list programatically.is there any API's available for this.....

Answer (score 1):

```
    -(void)showPersonViewController:(NSString *)nameInContact
{
    // Fetch the address book 
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    // Search for the person  in the address book
    NSArray *people = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, CFSTR(nameInContact));
    // Display the information if found in the address book 
    if ((people != nil) && [people count])
    {
        ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)[people objectAtIndex:0];
        ABPersonViewController *picker = [[[ABPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        picker.personViewDelegate = self;
        picker.displayedPerson = person;
        // Allow users to edit the person’s information
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
    else 
    {
        // Show an alert if the person is not in Contacts
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not find %@ in the Contacts application", nameInContact] 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

    [people release];
    CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the contacts programmatically and edit them using ABAddressBook.framework.

You can find documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html

and programming guide here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html

Comment: yes this is possible but the scenario is that when user taos contact in APP,it will ask him whether u belongs to UK or not.it he select yes  we should add +49 in front of existing contact but it shouldn't disturb the native contact.the contact list must be same.but in the APP only we have to add +49 to that...

Comment: if you study the links thoroughly, you will find a way to access the contacts and add the number to it before showing to the user only inside your app. But you will need your own view for showing contacts then. you wont be able to use people picker. Or you could copy the addressbook in your app and add ur desired prefix.

Comment: i am not maintaining any contacts in app. i am accessing the native contact.i want to add +49 when making call in APP.after ending the call the number should not be changed...

Comment: would you read the comments carefully. I said "access the contacts and add the number to it before showing to the user only inside your app". this means get the contact in an NSString variable and append +49 to that number and use it for making the call. Nobody is asking you to maintain contacts